# Как стилизировать "select"?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, html-select

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как лучше стилизировать данный "select" ?

Answer (score 3):

По нормальному пути развития, Вы не стилизируете стандартный селек до такого состояния. Это будет нечто вроде dropdown.
Рекомендую посмотреть уже на готовые решения, которые вы сможете без труда стилизировать например [вот](https://github.com/HubSpot/select) или [вот](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/), их много, это как пример. Разумеется вы можете это все не использовать, а лишь посмотреть как сделано там и сделать по своему, в любом случае Вы поймете как получить желаемый эффект.
В случае если этот селект вам нужен только для навигации, предлагаю Вам отказаться от идеи select и сделать обычный  dropdown